# How one can save images in emacs?

Tags: image-mode

I am trying to open images in image-mode and apply some modifications and finally save the image with image-save. Please refer here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Showing-Images.html

Something strange happens that some times buffer reverts to the original image! But most commonly, I have the buffer to an image, but image is saved untransformed!

So, what's going wrong here?!

Comment: So, as an example, you are opening e.g. a PNG file, rotating it 90 degrees and then you try to save the rotated image to a file - is that correct?